Secure Firestore credentials for a desktop app
I am creating a desktop application using python and firebase. In this app I wanted to use Firestore Database and store all the data, but, that is possible by giving the path to the privatekey.json file that I have. This might become a security issue, as this app that I am creating is open source and for linux systems which means it is not compiled and I will be packaging the source files. I don't want to have the database deleted by some malicious entity. I would like to know if there is any method to upload the data that user provides to the database but somehow not store the privatekey.json file in plaintext on the system.
I have tried to implement user authentication using email and password but my credentials still need to be passed in firebase module.

It sounds like you're using an SDK that is meant for server-side development, as it uses the private key file to authorize its usage.
For client-side applications you should never use such a mechanism, as sharing your administrative credentials with untrusted users is a huge security risk.
I recommend using one of the documented client-side SDKs that Firebase provides or (if no such SDK exists for your platform of choice) use the REST API to access Firebase with a Firebase ID token.
